# if statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying to learn rails by doing some labs in railsforzombies, I am in  lab3  (if statements).

It has two tables:

- Zombies{id, name, graveyard}
- Tweets{id, status, zombie_id}

**Objective**
*In the each block, if a Zombie has more than 1 tweet, print out SMART ZOMBIE*

```
 <% zombies = Zombie.all %>

<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>
      <%= zombie.name %>
      # add if statement here
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I have tried some solutions but I get it wrong.

Answer (score 8):

```
<% if zombie.tweets.size > 1 %>
  Smart Zombie!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

`<%= 'SMART ZOMBIE' if zombie.tweets.size > 1 %>`

Note: count/length/size are all [subtly different](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size).

Edit: more than 1.

Comment: Oh yeah, `.any?` would be better.

Comment: Ohh yeah it works, I think I have hard time understanding the syntax of ruby/rails. How do I do this: "In the each block, make the Zombie's name link to it's edit page" - I have tried: <%= link_to "Edit", edit_tweet_path(tweet)%>..

Comment: This is wrong as it will not work for two reasons. 1) don't use `size`, use `count` instead as it does an SQL count rather than a Ruby one 2) this will return "SMART ZOMBIE" for zombies that only have one tweet.

Comment: any? won't work because he wants only zombies that have more than one tweet, not zombies with at least one tweet.

Comment: This will work, but it will leave an empty line if the condition is false

Answer (score 5):

This works!!

```
<% zombies = Zombie.all %>
<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>
      <%= zombie.name %>
      <%= 'SMART ZOMBIE' if zombie.tweets.count > 1 %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will work, but it will leave an empty line if the condition is false

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li> 
      <%= link_to zombie.name, edit_zombie_path(zombie) %> 
      <%= 'Smart Zombie' if zombie.tweets.count > 1 %>  
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was alternately able to make the following work and pass on, would love to hear if this is bad or not.

---

In the each block, if a Zombie has more than 1 tweet, print out SMART ZOMBIE

```
<% zombies = Zombie.all %>

<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>
      <%= zombie.name %>
      if zombie > 1 tweet put "SMART ZOMBIE"
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>

      <%= zombie.name %>
      <% if zombie.tweets.size > 1 %>
      SMART ZOMBIE
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if zombie.tweets.count > 1 %>
  <em> SMART ZOMBIE </em>
<% end %>
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, it works!

```
<ul>
     <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
         <li>
             <%= zombie.name %>
             <% if zombie.tweets.length >  1 %>
                 SMART ZOMBIE
             <% end %>
         </li>
     <% end %>
</ul>
```